# How to handle clicks within RecyclerViewHolder

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I am new to android and below is my `RecyclerAdapter` class which extends `RecyclerView`. I tried to set an `onClicklistener` within my `RecyclerViewHolder` but I have failed to call a new activity cause I seem not to know how to get a context reference from the adapter. Any help will be appreciated.

```
public class TabFragmentNews extends Fragment {
private static final String ARG_EXAMPLE = "this_is_a_constant";
private String example_data;
private RecyclerView recyclerView;
ProgressBar progressBar;


@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_news, container, false);

    progressBar = (ProgressBar) view.findViewById(R.id.progressBarNews);
    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.recyclerview_news);
    //Executing The Async Task Class Here
    newsupdate();
    return view;
}

//Method For Executing The Async Task
public void newsupdate() {
    new BackgroundTask(getActivity()).execute();
}

//Checking for internet/network connection here


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    example_data = getArguments().getString(ARG_EXAMPLE);
    Log.i("Fragment created with ", example_data);
}

public static TabFragmentNews newInstance(String example_argmument) {
    TabFragmentNews tabFragmentNews = new TabFragmentNews();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putString(ARG_EXAMPLE, example_argmument);
    tabFragmentNews.setArguments(args);
    return tabFragmentNews;
}

//AsynTask Class for Downloading News Information
class BackgroundTask extends AsyncTask<Void, News, Void> {

    Context ctx;
    Activity activity;
    RecyclerView.Adapter adapter;
    RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager;
    ProgressDialog progressDialog;
    ArrayList<News> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();

    public BackgroundTask(Context ctx) {
        this.ctx = ctx;
        activity = (Activity) ctx;
    }

    String json_string = "http://doubleclickug.com/app/newtest.php";

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(ctx);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        adapter = new RecyclerAdapter(getContext(),arrayList);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

        progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        try {
            URL url = new URL(json_string);
            HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            InputStream inputStream = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
            StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
            String line;

            while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                stringBuilder.append(line + "\n");
            }
            httpURLConnection.disconnect();
            String json_string = stringBuilder.toString().trim();
            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(json_string);
            JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("server_response");
            int count = 0;
            while (count < jsonArray.length()) {
                JSONObject JO = jsonArray.getJSONObject(count);
                count++;
                News news = new News(JO.getString("details"));
                publishProgress(news);
                //Thread.sleep(100);
            }

            Log.d("JSON STRING", json_string);

        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            //} catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(News... values) {
        arrayList.add(values[0]);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
        //progressDialog.dismiss();
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);

    }
}

//RecyclerAdapter Class for populating recycler view with Information
class RecyclerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerAdapter.RecyclerViewHolder> {

    ArrayList<News> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();

    public static final int TYPE_HEAD = 0;
    public static final int TYPE_LIST = 1;
    Context context;

    public RecyclerAdapter(Context context,ArrayList<News> arrayList) {
        this.arrayList = arrayList;
    }

    @Override
    public RecyclerViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        if (viewType == TYPE_HEAD) {
            View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.news_header, parent, false);
            RecyclerViewHolder recyclerViewHolder = new RecyclerViewHolder(view, viewType);
            return recyclerViewHolder;
        } else if (viewType == TYPE_LIST) {
            View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.news_row_layout, parent, false);
            RecyclerViewHolder recyclerViewHolder = new RecyclerViewHolder(view, viewType);
            return recyclerViewHolder;
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final RecyclerViewHolder holder, final int position) {

        if (holder.viewType == TYPE_LIST) {
            final News news = arrayList.get(position - 1);
            holder.Details.setText(news.getDetails());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return arrayList.size() + 1;
    }

    //RecyclerView Holder Class
    class RecyclerViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {
        TextView Details;
        int viewType;

        public RecyclerViewHolder(View view, int viewType) {
            super(view);
            view.setOnClickListener(this);
            if (viewType == TYPE_LIST) {
                Details = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.team);
                this.viewType = TYPE_LIST;
            } else if (viewType == TYPE_HEAD) {
                this.viewType = TYPE_HEAD;
            }

        }

        //handling Clicks of news elements here
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            //How Do I Call an Activity???
            context.startActivity(new Intent(context,NewsActivity.class));

        }


    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        if (position == 0)
            return TYPE_HEAD;
        return TYPE_LIST;
    }

}
```

After editing the code to the above:-The app doesn't navigate to the other activity, on clicking it crushes

Comment: stack trace please..

Answer (score 0):

Pass context as an parameter to the constructor of the adapter and use it while calling start activity.
**Example**

```
class RecyclerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerAdapter.RecyclerViewHolder> {

ArrayList<News> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
Context context;

public static final int TYPE_HEAD = 0;
public static final int TYPE_LIST = 1;

public RecyclerAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<News> arrayList) {
    this.arrayList = arrayList;
    this.context = context;
}
.....
.....


//RecyclerView Holder Class
class RecyclerViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {
TextView Details;
int viewType;

public RecyclerViewHolder(View view, int viewType) {
    super(view);
    view.setOnClickListener(this);
    if (viewType == TYPE_LIST) {
        Details = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.team);
        this.viewType = TYPE_LIST;
    } else if (viewType == TYPE_HEAD) {
        this.viewType = TYPE_HEAD;
    }

}

//handling Clicks of news elements here
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    context.startActivity(new Intent(context,ActivityTwo.class));


   }
}
```

From your **activity** call adapter like this...
(For fragment use `getContext()` instead of `this`)

```
RecyclerAdapter adapter = new RecyclerAdapter(this,mArrayList);
```

Comment: i believe this answer is right, but when i use RecyclerAdapter adapter = new RecyclerAdapter(getcontext(),mArrayList); which i executed within my onPreExecute(). the app crushes on clicking. what could be wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Pass the context through the constructor and do this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(context, YourActivityToStart.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

In your code change this:

```
public RecyclerAdapter(Context context,ArrayList<News> arrayList) {
    this.arrayList = arrayList;
}
```

to

```
public RecyclerAdapter(Context context,ArrayList<News> arrayList) {
    this.arrayList = arrayList;
    this.context  = context;
}
```

and inside your adapter change this line:

```
adapter = new RecyclerAdapter(getContext(),arrayList);
```

to

```
adapter = new RecyclerAdapter(getActivity(),arrayList);
```

Comment: i did that but problem is i get an error within my onPreExecute() where i set my adapter = new RecyclerAdapter(getcontext(),arrayList);i have edited my question and added all the code, please look at it again and give me clue. thnkx

Answer (score 0):

```
  class RecyclerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerAdapter.RecyclerViewHolder> {

    ArrayList<News> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();

    public static final int TYPE_HEAD = 0;
    public static final int TYPE_LIST = 1;
    Context context;
    public RecyclerAdapter(Context context,ArrayList<News> arrayList) {
        this.arrayList = arrayList;
this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public RecyclerViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        if (viewType == TYPE_HEAD) {
            View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.news_header, parent, false);
            RecyclerViewHolder recyclerViewHolder = new RecyclerViewHolder(view, viewType);
            return recyclerViewHolder;
        } else if (viewType == TYPE_LIST) {
            View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.news_row_layout, parent, false);
            RecyclerViewHolder recyclerViewHolder = new RecyclerViewHolder(view, viewType);
            return recyclerViewHolder;
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final RecyclerViewHolder holder, final int position) {

        if (holder.viewType == TYPE_LIST) {
            News news = arrayList.get(position - 1);
            holder.Details.setText(news.getDetails());
            holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new Listener(news));
             holder.Details.setOnClickListener(new Listener(news));
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return arrayList.size() + 1;
    }


    class Listener  implements View.OnClickListener
    {
    News news;
    Listener(News news)

    {
    this.news = news;
    }
     //handling Clicks of news elements here
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            //how do I call a new Activity???
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, YourActivityToStart.class);
context.startActivity(intent);
        }
    }

    //RecyclerView Holder Class
    class RecyclerViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        TextView Details;
        int viewType;
    View itemView;
        public RecyclerViewHolder(View view, int viewType) {
            super(view);
           this.itemView =view;
            if (viewType == TYPE_LIST) {
                Details = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.team);
                this.viewType = TYPE_LIST;
            } else if (viewType == TYPE_HEAD) {
                this.viewType = TYPE_HEAD;
            }

        }




    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        if (position == 0)
            return TYPE_HEAD;
        return TYPE_LIST;
    }
```

Comment: i have tried this and i believe would be right answer but, the problem is, from my onPreExecute am setting my adapter to an arrayList.      
            
            adapter = new RecyclerAdapter(arrayList);  i get an error requesting to create constructor or remove 1st parameter from method(public RecyclerAdapter())

Comment: dont set your adapter in preExecute Set the adapter in PostExecute

Answer (score 0):

When creating a recycler views adapter in the constructor take in a custom designed interface for your recycler views item. Here i have designed one for u:

A class level variable for the listener:

```
private CustomItemsClickListener mCardViewClickListener;

public interface CustomItemsClickListener {

    public void onCardViewItemClicked(View itemView, int position);
```

//you can add some more params also according to ur need.
    }

Constructor of ur recyclerview:

```
public CustomRecyclerViewAdapter(ArrayList<SomedataForYourItems> dataForItemsList,                                        CustomItemsClickListener mCardViewClickListener){

    this.mCardViewClickListener = mCardViewClickListener;
    this.dataForItemsList= dataForItemsList;
}
```

**From the recyclerView adapter class; i hope u have a custom view holder; like this u can call (a generic example):**

```
public class CustomViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener{

    public TextView tv1;
    public Button btnCustom1, btnCustom2;
    public CardView container;

    public CustomOrdersViewHolder(View view) {
        super(view);

        container = (CardView) view.findViewById(R.id.item_view);
        tv1= (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tv1);
        btnCustom1= (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btnCustom1);
        btnCustom2= (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btnCustom1);

        btnCustom1.setOnClickListener(this);
        btnCustom2.setOnClickListener(this);
   }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View cardViewitems) {
     mCardViewClickListener.onCardViewItemClicked(cardViewitems, getAdapterPosition());
    }
}
```

**On the caller end u can do this:**

```
mAdapter = new CustomRecyclerViewAdapter(getYourArrayListData(),
            new CustomRecyclerViewAdapter.CustomItemsClickListener () {
                @Override
                public void onCardViewItemClicked(View view, int position) {

                    //TODO cardview click
                    switch (view.getId()) {

                        case R.id.btnCustom1:
                            // TODO some actions for btn1
                            break;

                        case R.id.btnCustom2:
                            // TODO some actions for btn2
                            break;

                    }
                }
            });
    mYRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
```

Comment: i have edited the question and added the all class of code. requesting you look at it again and give me a clue on how i can achieve a successful onclick. thnkx